# Found error after adding identity in my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, scaffolding, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vybCJ.png)

I tried any possible changes but could not able to solve this please if any one know about this help me out

Could not find any solution.

When I deleted identity it works properly, but when I add new scaffolded item, it shows the error mentioned.

Comment: I'd refer you to Jon Skeet's [helpful hints](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) on how to write a good question. Say at least, what "identity" are you talking about? What have you tried (not "any possible changes")?

Comment: Could you please share your `dataAccessLayer` details? You have to register your repository in your `program.cs` while `building the app` which is missing here.

Comment: For instance, you should do like this `builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();`

Comment: i already add scoped which you mentioned above for unitofwork

Answer (score 1):

> I tried any possible changes but could not able to solve this please
> if any one know about this help me out

Well, lets explain your error details:

[image]

As the error clearly describes that you have `DataAccessLayer` class file with your project which contains `IUnitOfWork` under the `IRepositoty folder` which you haven't register in your `program.cs` file as a result you have encountered  that specific error.

**Solution:**

Resolve the current error, you have to register all the `Interface` and its `Implementation` just right before your `var app = builder.Build();`

So your `AddScoped` should be as following:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAnotherService, AnotherService>();
.... So on
```

**Note:** Point to keep in mind all the `Interface` and `Implementation` within your `DataAccessLayer` should be `scopped` before calling `builder.Build()`

Comment: actually if i deleted the scaffolding identity,it works properly,but after adding identity than error will apears,so scoped works properly before adding identity

Comment: Yes, I got your point, as the error tell us may be there are dependency you keep on `DataAccessLayer` with your `Identity`. By the way, could you please share your `identity details` and `DataAccessLayer`  so that it would be more easier to assist you.

Comment: @hassanghori hi how did you resolve this error?